# WKWebView Authorization

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am would like open a website, using a password/username (basic)Authorization in a WKWebView.
To do that I use the method `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = WKWebView()
    container.addSubview(webView)
    let urlStr = "https://vplan.bielefeld-marienschule.logoip.de/subst_002.htm"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void){
    if challenge.protectionSpace.host == "https://vplan.bielefeld-marienschule.logoip.de/subst_002.htm" {
        let userStr = "********"
        let passwordStr = "********"
        let credential = URLCredential(user: userStr, password: passwordStr, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.bounds.width, height: container.bounds.height)
    webView.frame = frame
```

But for some reason, it does not work.
Adding the code line

```
completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, credential)
```

like in the description here: [Authentication with WKWebView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177751/authentication-with-wkwebview-in-swift) produced an error.
I have also tried to change the `challenge.protectionSpace.host` into `vplan.bielefeld-marienschule.logoip.de:443` which is shown as the login adress in the  [Safari pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uttd.png) and into the IP-Adress of the server (93.206.31.253).

Hope you can help me.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have not set the navigation delegate of the web view to your controller.

Change the definition of your controller to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate
```

And after creating your web view, set the navigation delegate to your controller:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Depending on if you are using Swift 3, you may need to change the signature of the method to [`webView(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455638-webview).

Comment: Unfortunately your last hint leads to anther Error: Thread 1: signal SIGABART in the class AppDelegate.swift .

Comment: SIGABART is an exception - what does the exception say?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Yes, I figured that much. What is the exception message? If you can't see it, put an exception breakpoint, and when on the top line of the stack, type `po $arg1` in the debugger.

Comment: error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't read the value of register rdi       error: errored out in DoExecute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression

Comment: No, that doesn't look like an exception message.

Comment: Completion handler passed to - [test.ViewController                                         webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:] was not called(null)