# Unable to load URL in Hybrid Webview Xamarin forms

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

`https://spo.mcd.com/sites/seeit_development3/brand/cognizant-test-brand-05242017` this is the URL that i try to open in HybridWebView.

I get a 401 Unauthorized Error.
But The same URL opens in SFSafariViewController.

Have set the Following permissions in my info.plist:

`NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary {
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads : Boolean
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia : Boolean
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent : Boolean
    NSAllowsLocalNetworking : Boolean
    NSExceptionDomains : Dictionary {
        spo.mcd.com : Dictionary {
            NSIncludesSubdomains : Boolean
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads : Boolean
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion : String
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy : Boolean   // Default value is YES
            NSRequiresCertificateTransparency : Boolean
        }
    }
}`

Comment: You have probably logged in then on Safari sometimes. If I enter the URL here I also get a prompt for a username and password

Comment: Looks like authentication failed. You may provide the username and password in the delegate `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`. Reference: [authentication-with-wkwebview-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177751/authentication-with-wkwebview-in-swift).

Comment: DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler){
var crendential = new NSUrlCredential("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession);
 completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, crendential);
return;}}  this method gets called again n again infinitely.