# Swift - Get response from web (webview, safari, etc)

Tags: swift, ios9

I want to open a url inside my app and make login. After that, it'll redirect somewhere and it'll give me a response (200, or 500). **I'd like to get that response.**

Is it possible? I've seen that there are several options: webview, safariviewcontroller using SafariServices or even SFAuthenticationSession (but it's deprecated and the new one is iOS 12...)

What do you recommend?

Kindest regards!!

Comment: Explain more what you are trying to achieve opening url is not a big problem

Comment: Yeah, opening the url is not the problem. Getting a response inside the webview is. At least for me. That's why I'm asking for help :P

Comment: Did you tried some code in your project?

Comment: It's a very basic code. I've only tried to open a url. But I don't see any methods of any delegate to get that response. Do you know of any?

Comment: Then show that basic code...I will surely try to help if I can :)

Comment: Is a WKWebView /WKNavigationDelegate what I need? I'm beginning to think that it is

Comment: See this if this is your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177751/authentication-with-wkwebview-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use WKWebView with its delegate functions to archive this type of behavior.

Comment: Thank you Ashutos

Comment: see its correct that uiwebview is deprecated.but still you can use that and its very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **UIWebview** use JavaScript technique to load data within that web view. Like this way

```
    public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if let requestUrl = request.url, requestUrl.absoluteString.hasPrefix("check with your url prefix") {
        let absoluteStr = requestUrl.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "use to make url", with: "")

        if let absoluteUrl = URL(string: absoluteStr) {
            // do what you want with your url now.
        }
    }
}
```

Completion and Error delegate for UIWebView

```
    public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    if !webView.isLoading {
       //webview loading complete
    }
}

public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
{
    // Call failure callback except for the error of WebKitErrorDomain
    if ((error as NSError).domain != webKitErrorDomain) {
       // delegate error where do you want. 
    }
}
```