# Native iOS app with WebView not asking for camera permissions

Tags: ios, xamarin, safari, permissions, camera

I am writing an iOS native app with Xamarin. The native app only contains a few lines of code, it's basically a wrapper around a website. The native app itself consists of a WebView which loads a single page application.

The website uses this node package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/library) in order to implement a barcode scanner. The scanner uses the camera on the iPad in order to scan barcodes. When you begin scanning, the website requests permission to access the camera, then starts it to begin scanning.

If I access my website directly through Safari on the iPad, then the scanner works perfectly. When I make the call to begin scanning, Safari requests permission to access the camera, I grant it, and it works.

When I use my native app to access the website (which again, just consists of a WebView) then I never get the permission request to access the camera. The div that the barcode scanner resides within just shows a blank white background.

I have added the NSCameraUsageDescription tag to my Info.plist and given it a sufficiently long description. I added a reference to a NuGet package that allows you to manually request permission to the camera. I also tried manually going into the iPad's app settings and granting camera permissions that way. Nothing has worked. I never get prompted to access the camera. The camera never gets engaged/begins scanning.

I'm confused as to why the scanner works perfectly fine on the iPad within Safari but does not work within the native app?

Comment: do you use WKWebView or UIWebView ? if it's WKWebView make sure your are handling callback/delegate to show alert - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51667317/3145189

Comment: Did you find a solution? Which WebView are you using? WKWebView/UIWebView/SFSafariViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Apparently the UIWebView within iOS apps does not support camera access. Here's a link to the ZXing GitHub page describing it: https://github.com/zxing-js/library/issues/15