# How to display invalid SSL Certificate Alert and load URL only if user agrees in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, wkwebview

HI I'm working on a  `WKWebView` based web browser, Now the problem is I want to display some `Alert` when the URL being load, has *invalid ssl certificate* and if user still wants to open the URL then only load that URL otherwise display some error page.

I know how to bypass the bad ssl certificate using the following `WKWebView` `navigationDelegate` method

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
    let exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(trust)
    SecTrustSetExceptions(trust, exceptions)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
}
```

But this will load the URL without notifying the user, something I don't want.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: Hope that will help...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51667317/3197284 - contains example of showing alert dialog and triggering the completion handler when the dialog is closed (by adding action to the "confirm" button). 
You can do something which is pretty much similar.
In case the user do not want this page to load - you can cancel the authentication challenge and load request to your default error page.

Comment: @DocForNoc thank you for your reply. but this won't really help me as i'm unable to find out that the website being load has some certificate issue.

Comment: Can you provide an address with an invalid SSL certificate?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini you can use https://badssl.com for testing

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate a certificate’s validity with `SecTrustEvaluateWithError` and then check for an error e.g.:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    var error: CFError?
    if let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, !SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &error) {
        // OK
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
            let exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(trust)
            SecTrustSetExceptions(trust, exceptions)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
        }
        
        // Cancel
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
        
        // Show prompt
        let message = error!.localizedDescription + "\nDo you want to continue?"
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "SSL Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}
```

NOTE: you must call `completionHandler` in any case.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll check and will get back to you.

Comment: I have a custom alert class, I'm displaying that alert but the problem is the execution control goes back to the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
` and without calling the completionHandler this function execution ends, hence iOS throughs an exception. How to make this function wait until user decide something on my custom alert?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma From my tests if you strong hold `completionHandler` the app doesn't crash even if the function exits. Crash appears on completionHandler's deinit if it wasn't called. For example if you try call  `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) }` - crash doesn't happen. You can hold `completionHandler` by a closure as sample code above or make a property `var completionHandler: ((URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)?`.

Comment: you're right! Holding the strong reference to `completionHandler ` will work and the strong reference stop app to crash and when user accept/reject to browse the website this handler can be called. Thank you for your efforts, really appreciate that.  You deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced some similar issue, the the below approach worked for me.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive 
             challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
     completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition,
URLCredential?) -> Void) {

var error: CFError?
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0); // Multiple requests may come to load into web view
self.pinningCompletion = completionHandler; // strong property
  DebugLog(tag: TAG, info: "WebView: didReceive challenge - ios12 or higher")
  if let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, !SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &error) {
    // OK
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
      let exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(trust)
      SecTrustSetExceptions(trust, exceptions)
      completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);// on completion of alert action
    }

    // Cancel
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
      completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);// on completion of alert action
    }

    // Show prompt
    let message = error!.localizedDescription + "\nDo you want to continue?"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "SSL Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(ok)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    } else {
        while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
        }
    }
  }
  else {
    let cred = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
  }
} else {
  DebugLog(tag: TAG, info: "WebView: didReceive challenge - fallback older versions")
  let cred = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
  completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
}
}
```